# How do you prevent the sound of it runs more than once in android?

Tags: android

When I click on the button operates the song, and when press it again operate interoperate
How can I make it when pressed again actuation sound again without overlap??

```
public class Circal extends Activity {

    Button sound = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sound);
    sound.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(Circal.this,R.raw.one);
            player.start();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an if condition if its already started

```
if(player.isPlaying()){
    player.pause(); // pause before doing anything
    player.seekTo(0); // go to 0 seconds
}
player.start()
```

Comment: @MonaAhmad on your onClick listener, just below your example code

Comment: sound.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(Circal.this,R.raw.one);

             if(player.isPlaying()){
                 player.pause(); // pause before doing anything
                 player.seekTo(0); // go to 0 seconds
             }
             player.start();
        
         }
     });